In freeradius, how to retrieve variable declared perl module to sites-available/default?
I have a perlmodule.pm with authorize, post_auth blocks. Took the code from Freeradius example.pl
perlmodule.pm
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
#  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA
#
#  Copyright 2002  The FreeRADIUS server project
#  Copyright 2002  Boian Jordanov <bjordanov@orbitel.bg>
#

#
# Example code for use with rlm_perl
#
# You can use every module that comes with your perl distribution!
#
# If you are using DBI and do some queries to DB, please be sure to
# use the CLONE function to initialize the DBI connection to DB.
#

use strict;
use warnings;

# use ...
use Data::Dumper;

# Bring the global hashes into the package scope
our (%RAD_REQUEST, %RAD_REPLY, %RAD_CHECK, %RAD_STATE, %RAD_PERLCONF);

# This is hash which hold original request from radius
#my %RAD_REQUEST;
# In this hash you add values that will be returned to NAS.
#my %RAD_REPLY;
#This is for check items
#my %RAD_CHECK;
# This is the session-sate
#my %RAD_STATE;
# This is configuration items from "config" perl module configuration section
#my %RAD_PERLCONF;

# Multi-value attributes are mapped to perl arrayrefs.
#
#  update request {
#    Filter-Id := 'foo'
#    Filter-Id += 'bar'
#  }
#
# This results to the following entry in %RAD_REQUEST:
#
#  $RAD_REQUEST{'Filter-Id'} = [ 'foo', 'bar' ];
#
# Likewise, you can assign an arrayref to return multi-value attributes

#
# This the remapping of return values
#
use constant {
    RLM_MODULE_REJECT   => 0, # immediately reject the request
    RLM_MODULE_OK       => 2, # the module is OK, continue
    RLM_MODULE_HANDLED  => 3, # the module handled the request, so stop
    RLM_MODULE_INVALID  => 4, # the module considers the request invalid
    RLM_MODULE_USERLOCK => 5, # reject the request (user is locked out)
    RLM_MODULE_NOTFOUND => 6, # user not found
    RLM_MODULE_NOOP     => 7, # module succeeded without doing anything
    RLM_MODULE_UPDATED  => 8, # OK (pairs modified)
    RLM_MODULE_NUMCODES => 9  # How many return codes there are
};

# Same as src/include/log.h
use constant {
    L_AUTH         => 2,  # Authentication message
    L_INFO         => 3,  # Informational message
    L_ERR          => 4,  # Error message
    L_WARN         => 5,  # Warning
    L_PROXY        => 6,  # Proxy messages
    L_ACCT         => 7,  # Accounting messages
    L_DBG          => 16, # Only displayed when debugging is enabled
    L_DBG_WARN     => 17, # Warning only displayed when debugging is enabled
    L_DBG_ERR      => 18, # Error only displayed when debugging is enabled
    L_DBG_WARN_REQ => 19, # Less severe warning only displayed when debugging is enabled
    L_DBG_ERR_REQ  => 20, # Less severe error only displayed when debugging is enabled
};

#  Global variables can persist across different calls to the module.
#
#
#   {
#    my %static_global_hash = ();
#
#       sub post_auth {
#       ...
#       }
#       ...
#   }


# Function to handle authorize
sub authorize {
    # For debugging purposes only
#   &log_request_attributes;

    # Here's where your authorization code comes
    # You can call another function from here:
    &test_call;

    return RLM_MODULE_OK;
}

# Function to handle authenticate
sub authenticate {
    # For debugging purposes only
#   &log_request_attributes;

    if ($RAD_REQUEST{'User-Name'} =~ /^baduser/i) {
        # Reject user and tell him why
        $RAD_REPLY{'Reply-Message'} = "Denied access by rlm_perl function";
        return RLM_MODULE_REJECT;
    } else {
        # Accept user and set some attribute
        if (&radiusd::xlat("%{client:group}") eq 'UltraAllInclusive') {
            # User called from NAS with unlim plan set, set higher limits
            $RAD_REPLY{'h323-credit-amount'} = "1000000";
        } else {
            $RAD_REPLY{'h323-credit-amount'} = "100";
        }
        return RLM_MODULE_OK;
    }
}

# Function to handle preacct
sub preacct {
    # For debugging purposes only
#   &log_request_attributes;

    return RLM_MODULE_OK;
}

# Function to handle accounting
sub accounting {
    # For debugging purposes only
#   &log_request_attributes;

    # You can call another subroutine from here
    &test_call;

    return RLM_MODULE_OK;
}

# Function to handle checksimul
sub checksimul {
    # For debugging purposes only
#   &log_request_attributes;

    return RLM_MODULE_OK;
}

# Function to handle pre_proxy
sub pre_proxy {
    # For debugging purposes only
#   &log_request_attributes;

    return RLM_MODULE_OK;
}

# Function to handle post_proxy
sub post_proxy {
    # For debugging purposes only
#   &log_request_attributes;

    return RLM_MODULE_OK;
}

# Function to handle post_auth
sub post_auth {
    # For debugging purposes only
#   &log_request_attributes;

    return RLM_MODULE_OK;
}

# Function to handle xlat
sub xlat {
    # For debugging purposes only
#   &log_request_attributes;

    # Loads some external perl and evaluate it
    my ($filename,$a,$b,$c,$d) = @_;
    &radiusd::radlog(L_DBG, "From xlat $filename ");
    &radiusd::radlog(L_DBG,"From xlat $a $b $c $d ");
    local *FH;
    open FH, $filename or die "open '$filename' $!";
    local($/) = undef;
    my $sub = <FH>;
    close FH;
    my $eval = qq{ sub handler{ $sub;} };
    eval $eval;
    eval {main->handler;};
}

# Function to handle detach
sub detach {
    # For debugging purposes only
#   &log_request_attributes;
}

#
# Some functions that can be called from other functions
#

sub test_call {
    # Some code goes here
}

sub log_request_attributes {
    # This shouldn't be done in production environments!
    # This is only meant for debugging!
    for (keys %RAD_REQUEST) {
        &radiusd::radlog(L_DBG, "RAD_REQUEST: $_ = $RAD_REQUEST{$_}");
    }
}

sub my_custom_function {
    my $CustomAttribute = 0;
    return $CustomAttribute;

}

In the above code I created a subroutine my_custom_function which holds the variable with hard-coded value.
I want to read this variable's value in sites-available/default file to compare the values.
I'm trying to refer the variable in below way
sites-available/default
if ("%{CustomAttribute}" == 0) {
#####Do Something
}

I've additionally added CustomAttribute to my freeradius dictionary as well.
ATTRIBUTE       CustomAttribute         17270           integer

While performing radtest I get below error when radius reaching the if block I added in sites-available/default file.
Output from radiusd -X
(0) Tue May 14 18:22:27 2024: Debug:     elsif ("%{CustomAttribute}" == 0) {
(0) Tue May 14 18:22:27 2024: ERROR:     Failed retrieving values required to evaluate condition

Can someone show me the right way to retrieve this variable from the perlmodule to compare it in sites-available/default file under authorize block?

"I have a perlmodule.pm" Please show the module, or the relevant parts of it

@HåkonHægland, Thanks for the comment. Yes I've edited the question accordingly.

According to this documentation https://wiki.freeradius.org/modules/Rlm_perl you might need to set the attribute in the %RAD_REPLY hash in the authorize() method. For example: $RAD_REPLY{'CustomAttribute'} = my_custom_function()

@HåkonHægland, I tried that method as well, No luck. I don't know how freeradius reads the variable from the perlmodule. Do I need to specify the filename and function in sites-available/default block?

@HåkonHægland, Looks like I solved the problem. I have to use &reply:CustomAttribute in sites available while using RAD_REPLY in my perl Module :-) Will post the details in Answer section. Thank you

After some trial and errors I found a way to read the variable from perlmodule.pm.
I modified authorize the block like below to get value as reply
sub authorize {
    &test_call;
    $RAD_REPLY{'CustomAttribute'} = 0;
    return RLM_MODULE_OK;
}

edited sites-available/default file as below to capture the reply value. This is suggested by freeradius here
if (&reply:CustomAttribute == 0) {
#####Do Something
}

